# Can I set a breakpoint in Xcode that gets triggered if ANY variable is set to certain value? I do not know the name of the variable ahead of time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

Can I set a breakpoint in Xcode that gets triggered if **ANY variable** is set to some certain value? I do not know the name of the variable ahead of time, so I cannot set a classic symbolic breakpoint of `myVar = 42`.

I also don't want it to be limited to one single file or line of code.
I want it to get triggered if ANYTHING, is set to, for example, `42`, or `@"foo_value"`, etc.

Is it possible?
Perhaps, some kind of wildcard pattern is possible with symbolic breakpoints? SOmething like `* == 42` where `*` is any variable/object?